# Wait until recyclerview has scrolled to position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with a recyclerview where I have to select last item in the recyclerview.

I first scroll to the recyclerview and then call performClick() method on the selected item.

Here is the code.

```
int latestPostIndex = reactionsListAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
rvReactionsList.scrollToPosition(latestPostIndex);
rvReactionsList.getChildAt(latestPostIndex).performClick();
```

latestPostIndex is populated correctly. Problem is the performClick is called before the scroll is complete and hence app crashes.

How can I make performClick() wait until scrollToPosition() is complete?

Comment: Isn't that what performClick() does? Also, thats not the problem. Problem is performClick() /code on click of item fires before recyclerview scrolling is complete. Which means the object at index latestPostIndex is null and hence app crashes.

Edit: I also tried adding code instead of performClick(). Its having same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` to your `RecyclerView` and listen to `onScrollStateChanged` wait for a scroll to be finished:

```
int latestPostIndex = reactionsListAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
rvReactionsList.scrollToPosition(latestPostIndex);
rvReactionsList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
            && linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == latestPostIndex)
            linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(latestPostIndex).performClick();

    }
});
```

P.S: Don't forget to replace 
`rvReactionsList.getChildAt(latestPostIndex)` with `linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(latestPostIndex)` as `getChildAt` doesn't return the last cell of `RecyclerView`..

Comment: Tried this code. Didn't work. Still gives me same error. calling performClick() on null object.

Comment: Updated answer for more clarity. the rvReactionsList.getChildAt(latestPostIndex) is actually wrong..

Comment: @KeivanEsbati I'll try again with layoutManager just to be sure.

Comment: Uhh.. @pskink I have a horizontal list which has many items. On selecting an item from horizontal list the same item is selected in a viewpager. Thats why I want to call performClick on the item which I want. So it automatically selects the appropriate item on the viewpager. basically I want to simulate a click as a user would do normally. 

How do I go about data model as you mentioned?

Comment: Your code works but only when I am trying to access last item which is not visible. 
When I am trying to access last item which is visible on the recyclerview that item is not selected. Any idea why?

Comment: I didn't quite catch the problem. it works but it lacks? can you explain your problem more specifically? It may helps.

Comment: Say there are only 3 items in horizontal list(All are visible). In this case code does not work and does not select the last item.

Say there are 20 items in horizontal list (out of which 7 are visible). In this case code works and it scrolls to end and selects last item.

Comment: Sure.. forgot about that.. before scrolling list first check if last item is visible => if visible perform click, else scroll list. Check visibility of last item just like this:
if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
            && linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == latestPostIndex)
            linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(latestPostIndex).performClick();

Comment: you dont need any `OnScrollListener` and `performClick` at all, why do you want to make such workarounds? instead you have to run the code on your data model which is called when you click particular item

Comment: @pskink  How would I go about doing that? Can you give an example? I would like to improve the code where possible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer selected was problematic. Some times it scrolled sometimes it didn't.

What I didn't understood was smoothScrollToPosition(index) or scrollToPosition(index) focuses / selects the item with the passed index.

The workaround in the answer is an inefficient way of doing things as it constantly keeps checking for the boolean expression when the user does not scroll the list.

All I needed to do was call notifyDatasetChanged() after smoothScrollToPosition and set an index called currentReactionPos(its used in onBindView() method).

Here is the code that worked.

```
// Select latest item after items added from server
                final int latestPostIndex = reactionsListAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
                currentReactionPos = latestPostIndex;
                rvReactionsList.smoothScrollToPosition(latestPostIndex);
                rvReactionsList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Happy that you finally found a way that works perfectly for you but please remember that title of your question was "Wait until recyclerview has scrolled to position" and you wanted to "Select latest item after items added from server". The answer you provided may satisfy your use-case but by no means satisfy what this question is about..